# Why does my Game of Life simulation slow down to a crawl within seconds? Matplotlib to blame?

Tags: python, oop, matplotlib

I'm learning OOP in python and so for a bit of fun I bashed out a GameOfLife simulator this morning. When it starts up it runs at about 20 cycles per second (due to the `plt.pause(0.05)` I added), but within seconds it slows down to ~ 2 cycles per second.

I can't imagine it's the algorithm itself, and I can't see any obvious sources for memory leaks.

Is matplotlib failing to dump the old plots, is that the issue, causing thousands of overlayed images building up? I tried adding `del im` but it didn't help...

This isn't important, really, but I feel I could learn something from the answer.

PS if you think my implementation is poor then do let me know, I'm keen to learn!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import convolve
import time

class GoL():

    KERNEL = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
                       [1, 0, 1],
                       [1, 1, 1]])

    def __init__(self, width, height, p=0.3):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.matrix = np.random.choice(a=[1, 0], size=(width, height), p=[p, 1 - p])

    def play(self):
        self.plot()
        while True:
            self.cycle()

    def cycle(self):
        c = self.eval()
        for x in range(1,self.width-1):
            for y in range(1,self.height-1):
                c_val = c[x,y]
                if c_val == 3: self.matrix[x,y] = 1 #Alive regardless of whether cell alive or dead
                elif c_val < 2: self.matrix[x,y] = 0 #Dead regardless of whether cell alive or dead
                elif c_val > 3: self.matrix[x,y] = 0 #Dead regardless of whether cell alive or dead
                elif self.matrix[x,y] == 1 and c_val == 2: self.matrix[x,y] = 1 #If a living cell with 2 neighours, live
                else: self.matrix[x,y] = 0 #Only other option is dead with 2 neighbours; die
        self.plot()

    def eval(self):
        c = convolve(self.matrix, GoL.KERNEL, mode='constant')
        return c

    def plot(self):
        im = plt.imshow(self.matrix)
        plt.pause(0.05)
        del im #Added to see if speeds things up; it does not
```

And to run:

```
gol = GoL(width=100,height=100)
gol.play()
```

Comment: The best way to find out would be to profile the code. Are you using matplotlibs `ion` or [`animation`](https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will see that the images of previous calls are still present by printing the number of images inside the `plot` function,

```
print ( len(plt.gca().images) )
```

In your case this number will increase steadily, even though you delete the image, because it is still part of the axes and hence get redrawn every iteration.

It would be much better to draw the image once, and then only update its data.

```
class GoL():
    # ...

    def __init__(self, width, height, p=0.3):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.matrix = np.random.choice(a=[1, 0], size=(width, height), p=[p, 1 - p])
        self.im = plt.imshow(self.matrix)

    #  ....

    def plot(self):
        self.im.set_data(self.matrix)
        plt.pause(0.05)
        print len(plt.gca().images)
```

This will result in an animation at constant speed.

---

Concerning the question on where to improve the code, there are two things:

1. use `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation`, as this is much more stable and lets you savely terminate the animation.
2. use conditions on numpy arrays instead of looping over all pixels of the matrix.

Full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import convolve
import matplotlib.animation as animation

class GoL():

    KERNEL = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
                       [1, 0, 1],
                       [1, 1, 1]])

    def __init__(self, width, height, p=0.3):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.matrix = np.random.choice(a=[1, 0], size=(width, height), p=[p, 1 - p])
        self.im = plt.imshow(self.matrix)

    def play(self):
        self.plot()
        self.ani= animation.FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), self.cycle, repeat=True, interval=50 )
        plt.show()

    def cycle(self, n):
        c = self.eval()
        new = np.zeros_like(self.matrix)
        new[c == 3] = 1
        new[c < 2] = 0
        new[c > 3] = 0
        new[(self.matrix == 1) & (c == 2)] = 1
        self.matrix = new
        self.plot()

    def eval(self):
        return convolve(self.matrix, self.KERNEL, mode='constant')

    def plot(self):
        self.im.set_data(self.matrix)

gol = GoL(width=100,height=100)
gol.play()
```

Comment: I added a solution which would be more optimal and could be run even faster.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. And because you've made a new array of 0s you can delete lines `new[c < 2] = 0` and `new[c > 3] = 0` I guess...

Answer (score 1):

Before reusing the canvas, you should clear the old figure. You can use matplotlib.pyplot.clf() to clear the current figure (http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.clf):

```
def plot(self):
    plt.clf()  # Clear the old figure
    im = plt.imshow(self.matrix)
    plt.pause(0.05)
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you, very straight forward!