# Issues with matplotlib Func.Animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, conways-game-of-life

I'm trying to do some animation with matplotlib (Conway's game of life, to be specific) and have some problems with the .FuncAnimation

I figured out different cases which partly worked (but not the way I want) or result in different errors. I would like to understand the errors and work out a proper version of the code. Thanks for your help!

The function called through the .FuncAnimation is `gameoflife` which uses the variables `w, h, grid` to update the image.

For the whole commented code see below.

#### Case 1: Global Variables

If I use global variables everything works fine.
I define `w, h, grid` global before I call `gameoflife(self)` through `anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, gameoflife)`

In `gameoflife(self)` I also define `w, h, grid` as global variables

```
w, h, grid = "something"

def gameoflife(self):
    global w
    global h
    global grid
    .
    .
    .
    img = ax.imshow(grid)
    return img

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.axis('off')
img = ax.imshow(grid)
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, gameoflife)
plt.show()
```

As said, this results in the animation as wanted. But I would like to get rid of the global variables, because of which I tried something else:

#### Case 2: Passing Objects

I don't defined `w, h, grid` as globals in `gameoflife` but passed them with `anim = animation.FuncAniation(fig, gameoflife(w,h,grid))`.

(I know that `w, h, grid` are still global in my example. I work on another version where they are not but since the errors are the same I think this simplified version should do it.)

This results in the following Error:

> TypeError: 'AxesImage' object is not callable

I don't understand this error, since I don't call ax with the code changes.

```
w, h, grid = "something"

def gameoflife(w, h, grid):
    .
    .
    .
    img = ax.imshow(grid)
    return img

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.axis('off')
img = ax.imshow(grid)
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, gameoflife(w,h,grid))
plt.show()
```

#### Case 3: Passing Objects with `fargs`

In the third case I try to pass `w, h, grid` with the "frags" argument of .FuncAnimation resulting in just the first frame. (Or the first two, depending how you see it. The "first" frame is actually drawn through `img = ax.imshow(grid)`)

```
w, h, grid = "something"

def gameoflife(self, w, h, grid):
    .
    .
    .
    img = ax.imshow(grid)
    return img

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.axis('off')
img = ax.imshow(grid)
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, gameoflife, fargs=(w,h,grid))
plt.show()
```

## Complete Code

I hope its properly commented

There are two parts (beginning and end) where you can comment/uncomment parts to generate the respective case. By default its Case 1.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

##defining grid size
w= 20
h = 20

##generating random grid
grid = np.array([[random.randint(0,1) for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)])

######
# Choose for different cases
######

##Case 1: Global Variables
def gameoflife(self):
    global w
    global h
    global grid

##Case 2: Passing Objects
#def gameoflife(w, h, grid):

##Case 3: Passing Objects with fargs
#def gameoflife(self, w, h, grid):

####### Choose part over
    
    # wt, ht as test values for position
    # x,y to set calculation position
    wt = w-1
    ht = h-1
    x,y = -1,0 #results in 0,0 for the first position
    
    # defining grid for calculation (calgrid)
    calgrid = np.array([[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)])
    
    # testing for last position
    while y<ht or x<wt:    
        # moving position through the grid
        if x == wt:
            y +=1
            x = 0
        else:
            x += 1

        #sorrounding cells check value
        scv = 0
        
        #counting living cells around position x,y
        #if-else for exceptions at last column and row
        if y == ht:
            if x == wt:
                scv = grid[x-1][y-1] + grid[x][y-1] + grid[0][y-1] + grid[x-1][y] + grid[0][y] + grid[x-1][0] + grid[x][0] + grid[0][0]
            else:
                scv = grid[x-1][y-1] + grid[x][y-1] + grid[x+1][y-1] + grid[x-1][y] + grid[x+1][y] + grid[x-1][0] + grid[x][0] + grid[x+1][0]
        else:
            if x == wt:
                scv = grid[x-1][y-1] + grid[x][y-1] + grid[0][y-1] + grid[x-1][y] + grid[0][y] + grid[x-1][y+1] + grid[x][y+1] + grid[0][y+1]
            else:
                scv = grid[x-1][y-1] + grid[x][y-1] + grid[x+1][y-1] + grid[x-1][y] + grid[x+1][y] + grid[x-1][y+1] + grid[x][y+1] + grid[x+1][y+1]


        # test cell to conditions and write result in calgrid
        if grid[x][y] == 0:
            if scv == 3:
                calgrid [x][y] = 1
        else :
            if 1<scv<4:
                calgrid [x][y] = 1
    
    # updating grid, generating img and return it
    grid = calgrid
    img = ax.imshow(grid)
    return img


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.axis('off')
img = ax.imshow(grid) #generates "first" Frame from seed
#####
# Choose vor Case
#####

## Case 1: Global Variables
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, gameoflife)

## Case 2: Passing Variables
#anim = anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, gameoflife(w,h,grid))

## Case 3: Passing Variables with fargs
#anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, gameoflife, fargs=(w,h,grid))

####### Choose part over
plt.show()
```

Thanks for help and everything

Comment: First of all it might be a good idea to check how other people are doing this. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46197292/4124317) but there a lot of questions about animations and still a lot about animating exactly the "game of life". [ask] states for a question to include in how far other resources are not helping, you're totally missing that point here. Second you don't need the game of life to find out the syntax of FuncAnimation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Case 2: You call the function and pass the result into FuncAnimation.

```
def gameoflife(w,h,grid):
    # ...
    return ax.imshow(grid)
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, gameoflife(w,h,grid))
```

Is essentially the same as

```
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, ax.imshow(grid))
```

which will not work because the second argument is expected to be a function, not the return of a function (in this case an image).

To explain this better, consider a simple test case. `g` is a function and expects a function as input. It will return the function evaluated at `4`. If you supply a function `f`, all works as expected, but if you supply the return of a function, it would fail if the return is not itself a function, which can be evaluated.

```
def f(x):
    return 3*x

def g(func):
    return func(4)

g(f)     # works as expected
g(f(2))  # throws TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

#### Case 3: You calling the function repeatedly with the same arguments

In the case of

```
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, gameoflife, fargs=(w,h,grid))
```

you call the function gameoflife with the same initial arguments `w,h,grid` for each frame in the animation. Hence you get a static animation (the plot is animated, but each frame is the same, because the same arguments are used).

#### Conclusion. Stay with Case 1

Because case 1 is working fine, I don't know why not use it. A more elegant way would be to use a class and use class variables as e.g. in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46196346/why-does-my-game-of-life-simulation-slow-down-to-a-crawl-within-seconds-matplot/46197292#46197292).

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I'm kinda confused with your answer to case 2. In my understanding, if you explanation is correct, case one shouldn't work ethier. Since I use there the same cobination of `img = ax.imshow()` and `return img`. If you now why it would be awsome (I wuold like to unterstand _why_ errors occour and not just avoid them). But I think using a class is a reasonable solution.