# How to display Conway's Game of Life from an array of arrays

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of lists called `game`.

`game = [[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, ...], [1, 0, 0, 0, ...], ...]`

Where `game[x][y]` gives the value at `x` coordinate `x` and `y` coordinate `y`

Where `1` means it is alive and `0` means it is dead. I have a function that will update the array based on the rules of Conway's Game of Life.

However, I can't figure out a good way of displaying this graphically.

I was hoping to use something like matplotlib and then I can just update it every 1/30 seconds if I want 30fps or whatever. Although, I'm not sure how to do this.

EDIT:

Here is what I wanted to achieve:

```
fps = 15
while True:
    plt.imshow(game, cmap='binary')
    plt.show()
    game = update_game(size, game)
    time.sleep(1/fps)
```

However, it seems like it saves a new image every time so this basically crashed my computer... How can I make it update instead?

EDIT2:
I tried again

```
def main():
    size = [125, 125]
    game = populate_game(size)
    fps = 30
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    # plt.axis("off")
    img = ax.imshow(game, interpolation="nearest", cmap="binary")
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_game, fargs=(size, game, img,), interval=1000/fps, repeat=True)
    plt.show()
```

where `update_game` returns `img` after running `img.set_data(new_game)` where `new_game` is the updated `game` array.

However, it still seems rather laggy.

Comment: First thing would be to type something like `conway game of life matplotlib" into any search engine.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I did, they all use global variables or don't explain anything.

Comment: Well, maybe, but they give you a start, and would allow to provide a [mcve], such that it would be easier to help with the exact problem you face. E.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46196346/why-does-my-game-of-life-simulation-slow-down-to-a-crawl-within-seconds-matplot/46197292#46197292) has the full implementation in the answer without globals.